# Windows Formアプリケーションでのロジック部とユーザーインターフェース部の分離について

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms

おはようございます。

表題の件について皆様はどのようにされていますでしょうか？

Windows FormアプリケーションをVisualStudio2010で作成しています。
GUIでインターフェースが作成できるのは便利ですがフォームをクリックしたりするとフォームのコード（例：Form1.vb）にイベントハンドラーが自動生成されてしまいます。

自分のような初心者にはありがたい機能なのですが度が過ぎるとフォームのコードが多くなりすぎて可読性が低下する原因になると思います。

このような時、皆様はどのような対応をされておられるのでしょうか？

自分の場合はフォーム（Form1.vb）に対して対になるロジッククラス（Form1_logic.vb）を作成し、ロジッククラスのコンストラクタとしてフォームそのものを引き渡し、フォームに対する操作の処理はロジッククラスに書くようにしています。

こうすれば元のフォームにはロジッククラスのメソッドに対する呼び出しだけですみますがこのやり方で何か不都合が発生しますでしょうか？

他にスマートな実装方法などございましたら紹介いただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

現状では

```
Class Form1

    Sub New
        logic = New Form1_Logic(me)
    End Sub

    Sub Button1_Click()
        logic.OnButton1Click()
    End Sub

End Class
```

というイメージであるということですよね？これは一般的な設計ポリシーの評価では

- Form1とForm1_logicが相互に依存している
- Form1_logicで扱うデータがForm1そのもので抽象化がされていない

という2点で難があるかと思います。

上記はもちろんクラス分割を改善するのがベストですが、この手の設計方針には多分に個人の趣味が含まれるので反対にForm1をまったく分割せずに可読性を上げるテクニックをいくつか紹介します。

## Regionディレクティブ

```
#Region "リージョンの名前"


#End Region
```

のような記述を追加することでコードの一部を折りたたむことができ、これでメソッドを分類すればコードが把握しやすくなります。

## パーシャルクラス

Form1.hoge.vbのようなファイルを追加し、

```
Partial Class Form1
End Class
```

と`Partial`修飾子を指定すればこのファイルはForm1.vbおよびForm1.Designer.vbと併せて1つのクラスとなり、関連している処理を別ファイルにまとめることができます。

---

※これらは設計を変更しない小手先の手法ですので、本質的にはデータバインドなどを含めた設計の改善が重要です。

Comment: @pgrhoさま

回答ありがとうございます。
そんな感じです。実際にはロジッククラスをクラス宣言のすぐ下のどのメソッドにも属しない場所（なんと言うエリアと呼ぶのでしょうか？）でDim logic as new form_logic(me)みたくインスタンス化しています。　実はパーシャルクラスは検討したのですが自分もクラス自体が分離されている方が良いと思い、あのような実装に至りました。　もしよろしければ後学のためにクラスを分割する方向性に役立つ書籍やウェブサイトをご紹介頂けないでしょうか？　よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @Peinyan 正直な話、Windowsフォームはコントロールを直接操作しても問題ない程度のプロジェクト/クラス規模に収め、複雑化したらさっさとWPFに移行するのが得策だと思います。しかしどうしてもフォームアプリでないといけないのであればWPFで主流の「MVVM」設計を持ち込むとよいでしょう。回答中にもありますが、「データバインド(http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fdotnet/chushin/introwinform_06/introwinform_06_01.html)」機能を活かすことでスッキリとした実装ができます。ただFormのバインディングは実装が不親切ではまるポイントも結構多く、自称初心者の方にはあまり勧められません。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。現状WPFは使用を予定しているオープンソースのコントロールがWindowsFormである事を考慮するとあまり積極的になれません。もちろん将来的にはWPFの採用は必須と考えておりますので参考のURLや皆様の回答を熟読して役立てたいと思います。

Answer (score 3):

クラス分割や抽象化は、ロジックに着目しがちですが、
画面（Windowsフォーム）自体にも適用できます。

例えばヘッダ部・フッダ部、ＯＫ・キャンセル・閉じるボタン、時刻表示など、
複数画面で汎用的に使えるコントロールやイベント（つまり共通の画面レイアウト）を
定義した抽象フォームを作成しておきます。
その抽象フォームを継承したフォームで個々の画面を作成する、といった具合です。
ソースが減るだけでなく、デザイナ上での管理も楽になるかと思います。
（継承部分のコントロールはロック状態で、触っても勝手にイベント等は作成されない）

アプリケーションによって向き不向きはあると思いますが、
イベントの記述のみ可読性が落ちるほど長くなるなるような
多コントロール多機能フォームということでしたら、
こういった手法も1つの解法になるかなと思います。

```
''' <summary>抽象フォーム</summary>
Public Class FromBase
    '全画面共通の閉じるボタン
    Private Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                          Handles btn.Click
        Me.ButtonClick(e) '★
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    '★もし共通のイベントに継承先で独自処理を追加したいならば、抜け道を用意しておく
    Protected Overridable Sub ButtonClick(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    End Sub
End Class

''' <summary>継承フォーム</summary>
Public Class FromA
    Inherits FromBase

    '共通でない独自のイベント・処理を記述していく

    '★
    Protected Overrides Sub ButtonClick(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Commit()
        MyBase.ButtonClick(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: なるほど、フォームとロジックの分離ばかりに拘ってオブジェクト指向の特徴である再利用の可能性について全く配慮が至りませんでした。参考になります。回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

確実にドメインを分岐したい場合、Formを使用すべきではありません。
WPFに移行を検討し、MVVMパターンを採用すべきです。

フォームアプリケーションでも、多少ながらもデータバインディングを使用できるので、MVVMのようなパターンを採用することは、可能です。

ですが、WPFに比べ、貧弱なものであり、下準備がある程度必要になったりしますので可能であれば、WPFに移行したほうがスムーズです。

いくつかのコントロールは、DataBindingsプロパティを公開しており、プロパティのデータバインディングに対応しています。

http://devlights.hatenablog.com/entry/20070413/p1

ToolStripMenuItemなど、DataBindingsプロパティを公開しない場合、継承したクラスにIBindableComponentインターフェースを実装します。

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/vegatech/20070911/1189507701

DataGridViewなどのリスト系のコントロールでもデータバインディング可能です。

http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fdotnet/chushin/introwinform_06/introwinform_06_01.html

---

- フォームの場合、PropertyChangedイベントは、UIスレッド上で発生させる必要がある。
- プロパティ名を文字列で指定するよりは、nameofを使用すべきです。※ VS2015
- 何度も言いますが分離を考えるならWPFに以降したほうが確実にスムーズでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。どうしても利用したいコントロールが２つありそれがWindowsFormなのです。よってWPFは使用しにくいです。将来的にはもちろんWPFに移行する事になると思いますので頂いたリンクやMVVMパターンをリサーチしてスムーズに移行出来るようがんばります。

Comment: WPFからでもWindowsFormsHostを使用してWindowsFormのコントロールを使用できます。※ WPF特有の回転・拡大・縮小などは、使用できません。